# how to check browser using jquery?

Tags: image, rotatetransform

how to rotate image angle using jquery? is it possible?

Comment: I sense some discrepancy between your question and its title ...

Comment: Sorry actually i want to ask both question and both in my mind so i couldn't recognize what i am typing

Answer (score 1):

To rotate an image, you might want to look at [this library](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/) for jQuery.

As stated above you can use [jQuery.browser](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser) to detect browser type, however if you are using this to determine what a browser is capable of you should really use feature detection instead. See the note at the top of the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

To check the browser use the jQuery.browser function. An image cannot be rotated with jQuery AFAIK.

Comment: I believe jQuery.browser is actually deprecated. You should now be using feature detection

Comment: Yup... you're right. I just looked at the docs. They say they will continue to support it though.

Comment: i have already use jquery's function for checking the browser, then also not detecting IE and FFox

Comment: actually image angle wise rotation is possible in FFox only, but won't support rest of all browsers. :(